# To get values from one column if the value in the other column is this

Tags: r

I am wondering how to do the following:

- I have a dataset on people's top 2 favourite drinks, where each row lists the drink, the ranking and how many people gave that ranking. The dataset is formatted this way

| Drinks | ranked | number of people |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tea | 1 | 4 |
| Tea | 2 | 5 |
| Coffee | 1 | 3 |
| Coffee | 2 | 3 |
| Juice | 1 | 1 |
| Juice | 2 | 2 |

I am stuck on trying to turn the above table into the following table:

| Drinks | people who ranked it 1 | people who ranked it 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tea | 4 | 5 |
| Coffee | 3 | 3 |
| Juice | 1 | 2 |

So far I am using the summarise function in dplyr, but got no luck after that.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = Drinks, names_from = ranked, names_prefix = 'People who ranked it ', values_from = `number of people`)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Drinks `People who ranked it 1` `People who ranked it 2`
  <chr>                     <dbl>                    <dbl>
1 Tea                           4                        5
2 Coffee                        3                        3
3 Juice                         1                        2
```

Comment: I'm actually working with a larger dataset, where for example for water 0 people included it in their rankings. Is there a way to do this with the summarise function? Using pivot_wider, it's not able to generate 0 for those, instead it does NA, which is not ideal. Also, is there a way within pivot_wider to rename the columns names entirely instead of using names_prefix?

Comment: @Jes, look up values_fill option for NAs.